# What to do if xpath for a link changes after loading for a few times while scraping?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I have been trying to scrape linkedin after entering keywords in the search box iteratively through a loop. There is a **See All** link present when each keyword is searched, which gives the related posts. After searching for 2-3 keywords, the xpath for that anchor tag is changing, forcing the loop to break and resulting in an error.

Here's the code I am trying :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(xml2)


try(rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = 'firefox'))
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.linkedin.com/login")

det<-vector()
cat("Enter user id: ");
det[1] <- readLines("stdin",n=1);

user <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"username")
user$sendKeysToElement(list(det[1],key="tab"))

cat("Enter pass: ");
det[2] <- readLines("stdin",n=1);


pass <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',"password")
pass$sendKeysToElement(list(det[2],key="enter"))

ex<-c("mba job","job referral","ca job","mba referral","high paying jobs")

for (b in 1:5) {
  Sys.sleep(10)
  search <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/header/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/input')
  search$sendKeysToElement(list(ex[b],key="enter"))

 Sys.sleep(10)

  key <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/div/a')
  key$clickElement()
}
```

There are many more keywords, for simplicity gave 5. The ***key*** variable holds the xpath of the see all button which gets changed when searched 'ca jobs'. It is followed by my code to scrape the posts.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: post html code of element, that xpath looks so wrong, there must be a common attribute to identify same element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something more generic to locate elements. For the search box :

```
//input[starts-with(@class,"search-global")]
```

For the element to click on ("See All") :

```
//div[contains(@class,"escape-hatch")]
```

Side note : You could loop over the urls instead of using the search box. With paste0, create a list of all the urls required :

```
urls = paste0("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=",vector containing your keywords)
```

Then use a loop or an apply function to iterate through that lis(url[0],url[1],...) and scrape the content you want.

Comment: the URL manipulation really helped and made my job easier. Thanks a lot.